# Build and run a development environment with Docker

Tags: symfony, vagrant, docker, lxc

We are trying to create a Docker container which will host and run our webapp (mainly written in PHP with Symfony2).

For the moment, the container embeds all the application code, cloned when building the image (through a Dockerfile). The app runs correctly, on OSX, through Vagrant (Precise64 base image).
We are now struggling to share the container embedded code with the host (Vagrant -> OSX) for development purpose (edit a file on the host OSX should affect the container code). 
Seems that there is no way to share this folder from container to the host. 
Sharing a folder from host to container (`-v` option of the `run` command) overwrites the original container folder. 
A soft link does not work as well since the hosts (Vagrant and OSX) could not read the original location.

I'm sure that the solution is with the Docker's volumes (http://docs.docker.io/en/latest/use/working_with_volumes/) but we have not figured out yet how to make it works.

Do you have feedback / experience on it ?

Comment: I have written a guide on putting your dev environment on docker. It's a bit old in docker standards so there may be places that doesn't comply with best practices. [Check here](http://play.thinkcube.com/development-environment-on-docker).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can share your file in OSX to container in the following line:

```
OSX dir(host) -shared fold-> /vagrant(vagrant) -volume-> container dir(container)
```

but the the file is saved in you host not container.

If you want save the file in container and share it to your OSX host, all your container file is in a aufs dir in /var/lib/docker/aufs/mnt/{container id}, your can share this fold to you OSX by the feather supported by vagrant or others:

```
container dir(container) -aufs-> /var/lib/docker/aufs/mnt/{id}(vagrant) -some-> OSX dir(host)
```

Comment: The first option seems correct IMHO. Share your folder on /vagrant and then use volumes to let the container access those files.

Comment: I thought about the 1st solution but embedding the code in the container let me build an image which is ready-to-go without having to first clone the repo, execute init scripts (like DB, depending on the app code), etc.

Comment: This methods works the same way the other way around. Embed the code in the container (using Dockerfile and RUN to clone the repo during build) and then expose the directory where the code is cloned to vagrant's /vagrant dir which you can in turn access from the host.

Comment: If you share a volume from host to an existing repo in the container, it overwrites the container's folder container so it's not a solution.

Comment: I wrote Docker Shell to make it possible to manage the source code inside a data container and share it with the developer using SMB. See http://dockershell.io/.